# Reseting a static variable back to zero when loading a scene unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem i have to use static variable because if i don't use it if i use normal variable italways prints (on point where i debug.log)  1 even if i click on gameobject   3 times. it works but when i reload/load a new scene a scene variable stays the same for instance 2  but i need it to be 0.
**Basically** it works fine i just have to reset variable after loading current scene aggain.

```
public static int end;

    void OnMouseDown(){
        end +=1;
        Debug.Log (end);
        if (end == 1)  {
            Vector2 pos1 = new Vector2 (-6,0);
            Instantiate (Redstar,pos1,Quaternion.identity);
        }
        else if ( end == 2 ) {
            Vector2 pos2 = new Vector2 (-5,0);
            Instantiate (Redstar, pos2,Quaternion.identity);
        }
        else if ( end ==3 ) {
            Vector2 pos3 = new Vector2 (-4,0);
            Instantiate (Redstar, pos3,Quaternion.identity);
            GameObject.Find ("ballon").SendMessage ("Finnish");
        }



    }
```

Comment: Are you using a singleton script?

Comment: i tried but it didn't work. can you write me how? maybe i made a mistake if you think it's working

Comment: If you are not using DontDestroyOnLoad function in your script, then @Woltus's trick will do the job.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? It isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an empty GameObject to scene and add script with this code to it:

```
void Start(){
    YourClass.end = 0;
}
```

YourClass is script with code from question.

Comment: It doesn't work now my variable at the point debug.log(end) is always 1

Answer (score 1):

If you use static variables in MonoBehaviour, theys basically need to be declared and initialized separately, and the initialization put into Awake() or Start(). Otherwise they will keep their old value when the MonoBehaviour is reinitialized on scene load, and you'll get issues when loading scenes.